# How to convert a variable and pipe commands into another variable

Tags: bash, variables

```
$USERNAME =$($INI$LNAME | tr '[:upper:]' '[:lower:]')
```

This is not working. How can i make it work?

Comment: The correct way to do this is: `username=$(...)`.

Comment: Also see: [Correct Bash and shell script variable capitalization](https://stackoverflow.com/q/673055/6862601).

Answer (score 1):

Your assignment should be `USERNAME=$(...)`.